# the Loading... Message in Grid when there is no data. ExtJs Grid

Tags: json, loading, extjs4.1, gridpanel

In my application, when there are no records on DB, the json i am receiving is as below.

```
JSON Message: {"totalCount":0,"responseObject":[]}
```

But in the grid the Loading... mask is not going off. It says Loading even if there is no data as in the image below.

[image: No records Image]

Please suggest me how to get rid of this when there is no data, i want to show the empty grid without this loading mask.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597892/extjs-load-mask-while-long-processing

Comment: Provide code example.

Comment: Your Store Reader doesn't detect the root of your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may know what your problem is, because I had the same issue.

For me, the reason why the loading mask wouldn't resolve was not because there were no records, but because I was trying to select the first record in the grid when there WAS none.

This throws a javascript error that looks like this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined "

Because of this error, it stops other Ext javascript processes, and the mask never gets a chance to resolve.

So, to solve this problem, I would make sure that your Store's 'load' event handlers do not try to do things with records that do not exist in the grid. It worked for me.