# Change cursor style while processing Ext.Button handler

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4, I have an `Ext.Button` with a handler function that takes a while to run. While it runs, the button looks like it's pressed and the cursor keeps looking like a pointer hand.

I'd like to change the cursor style to appear as waiting (i.e. the CSS style `wait`). This is the sample code I need to change:

```
function myHandler(button) {
    //1. TODO: Change the cursor to wait
    processingStuff();  // This might take 10 seconds
    //2. TODO: Change the cursor back to the default
};
Ext.application({
    name: 'Ext.Array.clean()',
    launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text    : 'My Button',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler : myHandler
    });
    } // launch
}); // Ext.application()
```

**Update:**

Thank you, hopper and Lauren, the missing piece was that I needed some delay before running the `processingStuff()` method as explained here: [Extjs Load Mask while long processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597892/extjs-load-mask-while-long-processing)

Here is a sample based on Lauren's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WbMSW/

The above sample does not work in IE and I'm not sure why, I guess the `hover` event on the button is not triggered in time, the only solution I could think of is using a mask or use `setLoading()` as Lauren suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/G9tqx/6/ (I can't use web workers because they are not supported in IE8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable your button, `button.setDisabled(true)`, it gets the class `x-item-disabled`(by default) which you can style in your css. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Xgx5x/

You can also use `button.setLoading(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set styles on the button element directly, using the [`getEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getEl) and [`setStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-setStyle) methods:

```
new Ext.button.Button({
    text: 'My Button',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    handler: function(button) {
        var el = button.getEl();

        el.setStyle({ cursor: 'wait' });
        processingStuff();
        el.setStyle({ cursor: 'default' });
    }
});
```

Alternatively, it is probably better to set a CSS class on the button and then set the appropriate cursor style in CSS. That way, if you want to add additional styles you can do so in CSS rather than cluttering up your Javascript.

Javascript:

```
new Ext.button.Button({
    text: 'My Button',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    handler: function(button) {
        button.addCls('button-working');
        processingStuff();
        button.removeCls('button-working');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```css
.x-btn.button-working {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use jquery to achieve your goal.

```
function myHandler(button) {
    $('selector').css( 'cursor', 'wait' );
    processingStuff();  // This might take 10 seconds
   $('selector').css( 'cursor', 'default' );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I see in the debugger the cursor style changes but the browser (Chrome and FF) wouldn't render it until the handler finishes. See the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PEMdX/1/