# Grid loadmask is not working during filter of grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a extjs grid with data in it, and I have a button that filters through the store for certain type of data, this filter I have also has a loadmask that should appear the moment you push the button and after the filter function has been completed the loadmask should dissappear however it does not even show before the button is pushed.

Here is the code for the button

```
Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').setLoading(true, this.el);
var allRecords = Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').store.data;
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-'  + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
};
var today = new Date();
var todays = today.yyyymmdd();
allRecords.each( function(record){
    var store = Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore');
    store.filter({
        filterFn: function (record) {
            return (record.data.expiry_date <= todays);
        }
    });
});
var complete = Ext.getCmp('complete').setDisabled(true);
var incomplete = Ext.getCmp('incomplete').setDisabled(true);

Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').setLoading(false, this.el);
```

I do not know why it does not work, shouldn't the loadmask show before since it is the first line to be executed. This is for the purpose of showing the user that something is happening the moment they push the button.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I just had to defer the function I had like this

```
Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').mask('Loading');

Ext.defer(function() {
            var allRecords = Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').store.data;
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-'  + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
};
var today = new Date();
var todays = today.yyyymmdd();
allRecords.each( function(record){
    var store = Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore');
    store.filter({
        filterFn: function (record) {
            return (record.data.expiry_date <= todays);
        }
    });
});
var complete = Ext.getCmp('complete').setDisabled(true);
var incomplete = Ext.getCmp('incomplete').setDisabled(true);
            Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').unmask();
}, 10);

//
```

Comment: another question real quickly, What is the difference between using mask() function and setLoading() function, they both seem to do the same thing, which one should i use before the deferred function

Comment: I think the two do the same thing (visually speaking) but the difference is that `.mask()` is more customizable as long as you can pass the text you want to show or a css for styles. `setLoading` only accepts `true` or `false`. Here the [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-mask)

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, JavaScript runs on a single thread. There is a lot of reading material, if you search for `javascript single thread` on SO or the search engine of your choice. 
However, you want to show the loading mask in the same function (and thread) which filters the grid. That won't work. Even if the layout engine will get time to actually show the loading mask, it won't be animated since the thread would be blocked with the filtering. And as soon as the filtering is done, the loading mask will be hidden again.

You will see the animated loading mask, if you would do server side filtering, because the layout engine will get enough time to show the loading mask and the thread is not blocked with the filtering.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597892/extjs-load-mask-while-long-processing#12601652) is a similar discussion with a workaround using timeouts.